# FB sharer and APP ID

Tags: facebook, security

I am using this `JS` code for my `FB` share button:

```
 fbURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?' +
            'app_id=000000000' +
            '&display=popup' +
            '&link=' + url +
            '&picture=' + encodeURIComponent(shareImg.replace(/ /g, "%20")) +
            '&description=' + shareTitle +
        '&redirect_uri=' + closeRedirect;
```

This code exposes my `FB APP ID`. Is this OK? is there any harm/ security breach doing that as long as you don't expose your app secret?

Comment: There is no harm. App ID are not secret in any way

Comment: BTW why the space-replacing in `picture`? `encodeURIComponent` will already encode a space correctly to `%20`. If you pre-escape it like this you'll just get a double-escaped `%2520`. Also `link`, `description` and `redirect-uri` would also seem to need `encodeURIComponent`ing.